# How to connect custom USB keyboard to ssh terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, keyboard, usb

I've tasked with developing some software on an embedded arm9 system (a TS-7600, FWIW) that has a custom USB device connected that provides keyboard, mouse, and 'device' functions.  I am trying to get this USB keyboard to send keys to my program while running in an ssh terminal session (my only way to interact with the system -- there is no serial port for a console or video output, only an ethernet and usb port.)  The device is detected and this was logged in dmesg during boot:

```
 [ 6.530000] <30>udevd[619]: starting version 175
 [10.480000] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
 [10.490000] input: HID 1c40:04d1 as /devices/platform/fsl-ehci.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input0
 [10.490000] generic-usb 0003:1C40:04D1.0001: input: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [HID 1c40:04d1] on usb-fsl-ehci.0-1/input0
 [10.500000] input: HID 1c40:04d1 as /devices/platform/fsl-ehci.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1/input/input1
 [10.500000] generic-usb 0003:1C40:04D1.0002: input: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [HID 1c40:04d1] on usb-fsl-ehci.0-1/input1
 [10.560000] input: HID 1c40:04d1 as /devices/platform/fsl-ehci.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.2/input/input2
 [10.560000] generic-usb 0003:1C40:04D1.0003: input: USB HID v1.11 Device [HID 1c40:04d1] on usb-fsl-ehci.0-1/input2
 [10.560000] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
 [10.560000] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

It looks to me like the device is recognized as keyboard, mouse and 'device', but the keys are not being received in my ssh session.

For testing, I plugged the USB component into a Windows machine, and it is immediately recognized as a keyboard and keys are received in the active program.  I am hoping that there is a way to force linux to send the device's keys to my ssh terminal just as it sends other keys.

Is this even possible?  Or maybe there is some way to connect my session to the system console and run my test there so that I see the USB keyboard inputs?

Comment: I've discovered that the *input-events* utility can get the (really) low level keyboard events (scan code, press, release) so I can probably find the source for it if I must, but I'd really like a more "normal" keyboard input method.